# difference between backstretch.js and backstretch.min.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

can anybody explain me what is the difference between backstretch.js and backstretch.min.js?

I am trying to use backstretch plugin but I am confused between both files how to use it and which one i need to use for displaying slideshow.

Comment: the second one is a minified version, i.e.: is processed so the size of the file is reduced (saving on network transfers). The text is syntactically and semantically correct, but pretty much unreadable (and hard to debug) for a human being. The common practice is having the unminified version for development (backstrecth.js) for development, and the minified version in production.

Comment: The `.min` file is most likely only a compressed version of the former, that can be used in productive environments to decrese the footprint of the application, minimizing space used on the server and improved download times, especially if the file does not get cached. For development it does not matter which one you use, unless you want to debug the code - then you should definitely use the uncompressed version.